# VMware Workstation 8 does not recognize USB devices any more: where to start?

Tags: windows-7, usb, vmware-workstation

I don't use host USB devices in my guests very often. They used to work in the past, but not any more.

I've read and checked [Host USB device fails to function in a VMware Workstation or Player virtual machine (1016809)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016809) and ["Host USB device connections disabled" in VMware?](https://superuser.com/questions/97014/host-usb-device-connections-disabled-in-vmware/129786#129786)

Everything there seems normal:

- no error messages in the windows event log
- VMware USB Arbitration Service starts normally
  (the VMware View USB service starts normally too)
- Guest VMs start fine
- No messages when starting VMware Workstation

Where should I look further?

Some more information:

*Host*

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- USB 2.0
- VMware Worktation 8.0.6 build-1035888
- VMware View 5.2.1 build-937772
- [All USB Hub drivers are Microsoft's](http://ericwijaya.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/vmware-usb-cannot-connect-to-host-usb/)

*Guests*

- Windows XP SP3 x86
- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- VMware ESXi 5.0

The USB sticks I tried are the same that used to work before on the clients (about half a year ago).
The USB sticks work fine on the host.

Since then, the host has been kept up to date (Windows, VMware Workstation and VMware View got updated).

Answer (score -1):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the "Run" dialog box.
2. Enter **cmd**
3. Type this in:

   ```
   sc config exfat start= demand
   ```